# Get distance/displacement between two points

Tags: java, math

I need to return the distance between two points (p1 = (x1,y1) and p2 = (x2,y2)) but return the negative distance if p2's values are less then p1's.

So that this example is true:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a5xE.png

√((x1-x2)² + (y1-y2)²) will always return a positive value, as distance cannot be negative. But what I need is more similar to displacement.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math

Comment: So, just get the distance with that formula, and then negate it "if p2's values are less then p1's.", whatever that means to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "if p2's values are less then [sic] p1's"?  Both values?   Just one of them?  If this is something you can check separately from the distance calculation (for which you should use `Math.hypot`, by the way), then do so.

Comment: "this example is true" only for you!!

Comment: Perfect sense if you understand vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you really want a vector. It has magnitude *and* direction. The magnitude is the distance between the two points. The direction is determined by drawing the vector from the start point to the end point. The choice is arbitrary.

A vector from (0,0) to (5,0) is the same length as one drawn from (5,0) to (0.0): both are length 5.  But one points in the positive x-direction; the other points in the negative x-direction.  The vector idea is more general.

In 2D rectangular coordinates, you have points p1 = (p1x, p1y) and p2 = (p2x, p2y).

The vector from p1 to p2 is:

```
p = (p2x-p1x)*i + (p2y-p1y)*j
```

where i = unit x-vector and j = unit y-vector.

The magnitude of p is

```
pmag = sqrt((p2x-p1x)^2 + (p2y-p1y)^2)
```

The unit vector from p1 to p2 can be had by dividing the vector p by its magnitude:

```
p(unit) = (p2x-p1x)*i/pmag + (p2y-p1y)*j/pmag
```

punit points in the same direction as p, but it has magnitude 1 (hence the name "unit vector").

Answer (score 0):

If it only has to be negative if the first point has a larger x value then you could just check if x1 is greater than x2 and if it is, multiply your result by -1.
That is unless I'm missing something